# Epson NX420 Printer USB Cable Shocks When Tip is Touched

Tags: usb

Is this supposed to happen? It happens every time the tip of this USB cable is touched. It has a silvery color.

Comment: Is the printer connected to a grounded outlet?

Comment: Yes, but its only a two-pronged cord so I doubt its actually grounded.

Comment: So it is **not** grounded!

Comment: Yes, that appears to be true.